# Condenser Shotgun Microphone Their Limits And Use In Dual Applications

Tags: microphone

I have an condenser shotgun microphone made by Audio-technica. Top of the line, I'm sure. It has a tip-ring-sleeve aka stereo jack on it. (I would gladly buy two Sennheiser $1,000 condenser shotgun microphones if my little experiment worked.) I was told to use two condenser shotgun microphones "so that sounds will be cancelled out". My goal: to record sound 10 feet to 100 feet away from the condenser shotgun microphones. I've been reading about use of mixers to plug two microphones into one PC. I have a sound card and Audacity. Were condenser shotgun microphones made for the capture of sound generated at distances or is that parabolic dish with microphone the answer to my prayers?